# Any idea for trignometry question

Tags: trigonometry

I thought about it alot . but could not get any start .

Can anybody provide me a hint

$$\sum_{x=2}^{44} 2\sin x^{\circ} \sin 1^{\circ}[1+\sec (x^{\circ} -1^{\circ})\sec (x^{\circ} +1^{\circ})]$$
$$=\dfrac{-\sin^2 {\theta_1}^{\circ}}{\cos \theta_1}+\dfrac{\sin^2 {\theta_2}^{\circ}}{\cos \theta_2}-\dfrac{\sin^2 {\theta_3}^{\circ}}{\cos \theta_3}+\dfrac{\sin^2 {\theta_4}^{\circ}}{\cos \theta_4}$$

For distinct values of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4∈\{1,2,3,\cdots 44,45\}$ then find the value of $\theta_1+\theta_2 +\theta_3 +\theta_4$ equals to

$a)106$

$b)53$

$c)92$

$d)100$

> Ans. $c)92$

Comment: Yes, you thought what ?

Comment: (-1) 123 posts and you still don't know how to ask a proper question.

Comment: @TMM Right on spot, I am sick of such users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$f(a,b)=2\sin A\sin B[1+\sec(A-B)\sec(A+B)]$$ 
$$=[\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)]\cdot\dfrac{\cos(A-B)\cos(A+B)+1}{\cos(A-B)\cos(A+B)}$$

$$=\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)+\dfrac{\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)}{\cos(A-B)\cos(A+B)}$$

$$=\cos(A-B)-\dfrac1{\cos(A-B)}-\left[\cos(A+B)-\dfrac1{\cos(A+B)}\right]$$

Now $\cos C-\dfrac1{\cos C}=\dfrac{\cos^2C-1}{\cos C}=?$

Here $A=x^\circ,B=1^\circ\implies f(x^\circ,1^\circ)=-\dfrac{\sin^2(x-1)^\circ}{\cos(x-1)^\circ}+\dfrac{\sin^2(x+1)^\circ}{\cos(x+1)^\circ}=g(x+1)-g(x-1)$

where $g(y)=\dfrac{\sin^2(y+1)^\circ}{\cos(y+1)^\circ}$

Can you take it from here?